# How to mathematically predict the energy transfer efficiency of a flowing fluid targeting a solid object

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

I want to calculate how effectively the energy possessed by a jet of water will be passed on a solid, not fixed object if the target’s material is changed.

For the sake of the argument, the flux is brought to a velocity of 100 m/s and is coming from a faucet with area of 5 cm². Resulting mass flow rate is therefore 50 kg/s. At the point of collision with the target the flux isn’t substantially slowed down, nor spread out.

The target masses at 60 kg,and friction with the ground is negligible. Furthermore we’ll assume this to happen in near-vacuum conditions to exemplify the process of prediction.

Now, to reiterate the subject of my the thread as a direct question: how can we measure with the data given the amount of KE transferred to the target if the latter is made of A) stainless steel B)ballistic gel C) soft wood?

Comment: The force would be determined by the size and shape of the object. Are you asking because the different materials have different masses and therefore different kinetic energies at the same speed? Are you expecting the gel to change shape? Are you expecting different friction? Friction would be negligible. At high Reynold's number, almost all the force on the object is a reaction force from deflecting the water.

Comment: The mass and shape are assumed to be constant, cause I’m more interested in knowing how other features of the different materials (density, elasticity, plasticity on the top of my head but probably there’s more) would change the effectiveness of the transfer.

Comment: You cannot have the same size, shape, and mass, but at the same time have different densities. Elasticity would make such a small difference to shape that it wouldn't matter. The gel could deform plastically (permanently) enough to matter. You would have to figure that out. Modelling this is a bigger topic than could be covered in a post.